# Is there any way to process this loop faster?

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, matrix, filter

I have the following code and it is taking a very long time to go through it... I dont think its an infinite loop but it is as follows:

```
Y = zeros(1069,30658);
D1 = LagOp({0,1,1,1},'Lags',[0,1,2,1]);
for n = 2:30658;
    for j = 2:1063
        if filter(D1,Ret((D1.Degree + j),n),'Initial',Ret(2:D1.Degree,n)) < 0;
            Y(j+3,n) = -1*Ret(j+3,n);
        else
            Y(j+3,n)=Ret(j+3,n) ;
        end
    end
end
```

Basically I want to flip the sign of the current element in the matrix if the previous 3 elements before it add up to being less than 0. Otherwise to leave it alone. Could it be the ... else statement causing the trouble here ?

Edited: I figured out a more efficient way but I am working on figuring out how to change it to 3 values ahead instead with the following code:

```
for n = 1:30658        
    Y(:,n) = RET(:,n);
    t = conv(Y(:,n), [1 1 1], 'valid');
    mask = [false(3,1); t(1:end-1)<0];
    Y(mask,n) = -Y(mask,n);
end`
```

So So for example, if I have a some numbers in an array given by **-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -1 -2 3 -2 -1**, then at the number -4 it would look at the sum of the previous 3 values (-1 - 2 - 3 < 0) and then change the sign of the value 3 ahead so -1 becomes positive and this would continue but the change in signs will not having any affect on the sums iterating for every row.

Thanks,

Comment: What are the functions `LagOp` and `Ret`? Can you make a simpler example without those functions?

Comment: `LagOp` is the function for LagOperator and `Ret` is just variable of my matrix. I actually found half a solution but I am interested in knowing how to change the sign of the next cell. So for example, if I have a some numbers in an array given by -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -1 -2, then at the number **-4** it would look at the sum of the previous 3 values (-1 - 2 - 3 < 0) and then change the sign of the value 3 ahead so -1 becomes positive.              If the sum is positive nothing happens. The code I have so far is :

Comment: Does your new example work. Can you give a small input vector and expected output vector?

Comment: I was able to figure it out using an alternative of taking the sum thank you

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think I helped your very much, though. :) But glad that you found another path.